# Matplotlib latex working directory / search path

Tags: latex, matplotlib

Matplotlib doesn't seem to find files in the current working directory when running latex.  Does anyone know where it looks for files?

The background is: I have a huge preamble that I `\input` into latex before processing (lots of macros, various usepackages, etc.).  In a stand-alone paper, I do `\input{BigFatHeader.tex}`.  So when I use matplotlib, I try to just input this file in the preamble.  The python code to do this is

```
matplotlib.rcParams['text.latex.preamble'].append(r'\input{BigFatHeader.tex}')
```

And I can verify that that file is in the cwd -- I see it when I `ls`, or I can do `os.path.isfile("BigFatHeader.tex")` and get True.  But when I try to plot something using latex, python spits out a big error message from the latex process, that culminates in
    ! LaTeX Error: File `BigFatHeader.tex` not found.
So presumably it changes to some other directory (not `/tmp/`; I checked) to do its work.  Any idea where this might be?

My minimal working example is:

```
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
matplotlib.rcParams['text.latex.preamble'] = r'\input{BigFatHeader.tex}'
matplotlib.rcParams['text.usetex'] = True
plt.plot([1,2])
plt.savefig('MWE.pdf')
```

Where `BigFatHeader.tex` might be as simple as

```
\usepackage{bm}
```

Comment: Not that this helped solve my problem, but in case anyone is curious, the working directory in my installation turned out to be `~/.matplotlib/tex.cache/`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I'm having the same error on my Ubuntu Lucid, matplotlib 1.1.0. 
There are two options:

Giving it a full path:

```
matplotlib.rcParams['text.latex.preamble'] = r'\input{/home/br/sweethome/temp/BigFatHeader}'
```

works for me. Notice that you don't put `.tex` extension for the files to be `\input`. If you don't want to hardcode the path, you can get it using `os.getcwd()`:

```
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import os

filename=r'\input{'+os.getcwd()+r'/BigFatHeader}'

matplotlib.rcParams['text.latex.preamble'] = filename
matplotlib.rcParams['text.usetex'] = True
plt.plot([1,2])
plt.savefig('MWE.pdf')
```

Or just read in your your file into a text string and set the `rcParams` with it.

```
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

paramstring=r'\usepackage{bm}'
matplotlib.rcParams['text.latex.preamble'] = paramstring
matplotlib.rcParams['text.usetex'] = True
plt.plot([1,2])
plt.savefig('MWE.pdf')
```

Comment: That works.  I also hadn't thought of reading the file into a string and adding it to the preamble string.  Thanks!

Comment: I am trying to figure out a way to do this in the matplotlibrc file, as I have many plotting scripts that all need the same preamble. Any ideas?